# Earth Engine String to call a geometry name within a loop for export

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have been trying to export some data using a loop but still could not figure out how to use the string that is in a list to define the region in the export function. I tried a few methods by searching but still could not figure this out.

```
var res_list = ee.List([750, 500, 250, 200, 150, 100, 90])
var region_list = ee.List(['area1', 'area2', 'area3', 'area4', 'area5'])

for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
  for (var j=0; j<5; j++){
    var res = res_list.get(i)
    var region = region_list.get(j)
    
//This ↓ is my latest attempt but did not know what I was doing

    var ROI = ee.String.evaluate(region)
    var scale = ee.Number(res).getInfo()
    // print(scale)
    var basin_name = ee.String(region).getInfo()
    var foldername = basin_name + '_sourcefiles'
    var filetype = 'DEM'
    
    
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: elevation,
      region: ROI,
      folder: 'Sourcefiles',
      scale: scale,
      description: basin_name + '_' + filetype + '_' + scale + 'm',
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
      maxPixels: 1e13
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have two elements that freeze the GUI: for-loops and **getInfo** statements. You have to avoid both of them. For avoiding that, you can use a double loop with the evaluate method as follows. The print statement inside the more inner loop allows to corroborate that the exported images will be produced as expected.

```
var res_list = ee.List([750, 500, 250, 200, 150, 100, 90]);
var region_list = ee.List(["area1","area2", "area3", "area4", "area5"]);

var filetype = 'DEM';

var exportImage = function(image, fileName, res, region) {
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: elevation,
    description: fileName,
    folder: 'GEE_Folder',
    scale: res,
    region: regions.filter(ee.Filter.eq("name", region)),
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
  });
};

res_list.evaluate(function (allRes) {

  region_list.evaluate(function (allRegions) {
    
    allRegions.forEach(function(region) {
    
      allRes.forEach(function(res) {
        var fileName = region + '_' + filetype + '_' + res + 'm';
        print(fileName);
        exportImage(elevation, fileName, res, region);

      });
    });
  });

});
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e5bc0cae29a05e0ff095c6f9403db31).

After running it at GEE code editor, I got the result of following picture for 5 arbitrary geometries in USA. There are 35 tasks for all possible combinations of resolutions and geometries. At the Console Tab, you can observe the 35 printed file names in its corresponding order.

[image]

I downloaded and visualized two of these 35 images in QGIS and, the results are consistent with the different considered resolutions and geometries; as it can be observed in following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem with your code above is where you define the ROI as `var ROI = ee.String.evaluate(region)`. I am pretty sure this results in an error. Probably your ROI's are coming from a FeatureCollection, in which case you can filter it to a specific region in each call to `Export.image.toDrive`.

I would also suggest using `.map()` instead of relying on nested for loops. Also, because `Export.image.toDrive` is a [client-side](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) function, you can use client-side objects directly -- there is no need to define them as `ee.List`, then use `.get()`, then using `.getInfo()` on them. Here's a simple example where there is a FeatureCollection containing two regions named "A" and "B", an `elevation` image, and using a nested `.map()` over the javascript objects. The inside `.map()` is using an anonymous function that is simply calling `Export.image.toDrive`.

```js
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([regionA, regionB])
// ^^ two regions with a property "name" set to "A" and "B", respectively.

var elevation = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/DEM/GLO30")
.select("DEM")
.filterBounds(regions)
.first()
//Map.addLayer(elevation, {min:1200, max:1300})
//Map.addLayer(regions)

var resList=[30,60,120];
function doExportbyRegion(region){
  resList.map(function(res){
    var roi = regions.filter(ee.Filter.eq("name", region))
    Export.image.toDrive({
    image:elevation,
    region: roi,
    scale:res,
    description: "Export-"+region+"-"+res,
    fileFormat:"GeoTIFF"
    })
  });
}

var regionsList=["A","B"] // another option (if the feature collection is large)
// would be:
// var regionList=regions
// .aggregate_array("name")
// .distinct()
// .getInfo()

regionsList.map(doExportbyRegion)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b5267e08e27ff4e372d25aa6c61f71b

Comment: This is the first time that I thought of this as client-side function. It all really make sense now. Thank you very much Oliver. I will get back with my result.